# shared_ptr initialization

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, decltype

A member is defined as

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<std::string, 6> > exit_to;
```

which points to additional data shared among others.
When try to initiate the pointer "exit_to". The correct way is

```
node_knot.exit_to = std::make_shared<std::array<std::string, 6> >();
```

But it's in another file and I'd like to keep the pointer type consistent, something like this:

```
node_knot.exit_to = std::make_shared<decltype(*node_knot.exit_to)>();
```

But won't compile:

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:798:54: error: '__p'
 declared as a pointer to a reference of type
 'std::array<std::basic_string<char>, 6> &'
         __shared_ptr(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __r, _Tp* __p)
                                                             ^ /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:93:31: note: in instantiation
 of template class
 'std::__shared_ptr<std::array<std::basic_string<char>, 6> &, 1>'
 requested here
     class shared_ptr : public __shared_ptr<_Tp>
                               ^ ../node_booker.h:757:20: note: in
 instantiation of template class
 'std::shared_ptr<std::array<std::basic_string<char>, 6> &>' requested
 here
                                                         n.exit_to = std::make_shared<decltype(*n.exit_to)>();
```

I'm under Ubuntu 12.10, clang++ 3.2, with --std=c++11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the reference from the type you are passing to `make_shared`. 
The following should work:

```
node_knot.exit_to = std::make_shared<std::remove_reference<decltype(*node_knot.exit_to)>::type>();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the type of `*exit_to` is a reference, and you can't have a `shared_ptr` to a reference.

You could remove the reference, but instead of finding the type returned by `operator*` and then stripping the reference off it, it's probably easier to just ask the `shared_ptr` what type it contains:

```
node_knot.exit_to = std::make_shared<decltype(node_knot.exit_to)::element_type>();
```

The nested `element_type` is the type stored by the `shared_ptr`.

Another option would be to add a `typedef` to the class and use it consistently wherever you need it:

```
typedef std::array<std::string, 6> string_array;
std::shared_ptr<string_array> exit_to;

// ... 

node_knot.exit_to = std::make_shared<Node::string_array>();
```

This is a lot more readable than using `decltype`

Comment: I would argue that the construct `decltype(node_knot.exit_to)::element_type` defeats the purpose of using decltype, since you are assuming (or adding the constraint that) the type of node_knot.exit_to has an `element_type` member, which isn't even true for most all STL types. Your second solution sounds better though. One observation though, including the name of the type in the typedef itself kind of devalues a typedef doesn't it. And advantage of typedefs is you can change the underlying container type of your string_array to whatever else without changing all occurrences in code.

Comment: However putting the `_array` in `string_array` kind of defeats that purpose, since once the underlying type changes, the name no longer reflects the type. See that dreadful thing called the Hungarian Notation, yuck: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: @Zadirion, so using `make_shared` doesn't already assume `shared_ptr`? As for the typedef, I agree in general, but it depends what the requirements are on the type. If it could be any sequence, putting `array` in the name would be misleading, but if it is a design requirement that it has contiguous elements of some string-like type then calling it a `string_array` is fine, and still works even if you change the implementation to `vector<string>`, or just to an array of different length. Without knowing more context you can't say if the name should be more generic.

Comment: my apologies, I overlooked the fact that std::make_shared was assigning back to node_knot.exit_to itself instead of other shared pointer, in which case what I said would have made sense.

Comment: as for `Without knowing more context you can't say if the name should be more generic. `. Well, being particular is a lot more unsafe than being general and encompassing all possibilities :P. `typedef std::array<std::string, 6> string_container;` Is a bit better. Still has `string` in the name, but at least `string` can be `std::string` or `std::wstring` or `CString` or whatnot. But that's just me nitpicking. Back on topic, your answer is quite good, I upvoted. I'd still go with remove_reference though just because its a more general approach. It all boils down to a matter of preference though